# Getting an error on a new website

Tags: errors

I'm getting the following on a fresh install of Wordpress:

thrown in /home/f4ye7hvx3rrq/public_html/deleteme.wphxbn.php on line 16 [04-Dec-2021 17:30:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_transient() in /home/f4ye7hvx3rrq/public_html/deleteme.wp3qbe.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/f4ye7hvx3rrq/public_html/deleteme.wp3qbe.php on line 16 [04-Dec-2021 17:30:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_transient() in /home/f4ye7hvx3rrq/public_html/deleteme.wptbsq.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/f4ye7hvx3rrq/public_html/deleteme.wptbsq.php on line 16 [04-Dec-2021 17:30:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_transient() in /home/f4ye7hvx3rrq/public_html/deleteme.wpfmoa.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/f4ye7hvx3rrq/public_html/deleteme.wpfmoa.php on line 16

Comment: I don't recognise deleteme.*.php. What's in those files? Could they be autogenerated by your host as part of the install? I don't think WordPress core creates them (but might be wrong)

Comment: [This question on WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/what-is-deleteme-xxxxxxxx-php) says they're CPanel installation scripts. If everything's working you can probably just delete them, although I'm not sure why they would be trying and failing to call get_transient(). I would double-check they look OK first though, and not malicious.